# Is there a lower bound for variance in terms of curvature?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, systolic-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If the Gaussian curvature of the metric $g= f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ is nonzero then $f$ cannot be constant.  This can be expressed by stating that the (probabilistic) variance $Var(f)$ of $f$ is nonzero (in a suitable domain).  If the metric $g$ has nonzero Gaussian curvature, then $f$ is nonconstant and therefore $Var(f)$ is nonzero.  Can this conclusion be quantified?  Namely, assume $g$ has curvature bounded away from zero on a suitable disk.  Can one get a lower bound for $Var(f)$?  This has immediate applications to a stronger version of Loewner's torus inequality with isosystolic defect term a la Bonnesen, see http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0803.0690 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0553

Note 1.  The Gaussian curvature of the metric $g= f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ is given by $K=\frac{-1}{2f^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)\log f$, so that the problem involves partial differential inequalities for the Laplacian.

Note 2. To restate the curvature hypothesis more carefully: we have a metric $r$-disk (for the metric $g$) where the curvature is bounded below by an $\epsilon>0$. The problem is to obtain a lower bound for $Var(f)$ in terms of $r$ and $\epsilon$ (certainly the estimate will become weaker as $r$ gets smaller).

Note 3 (reformulation along the lines of Robert's suggestion). On a fixed domain $\Omega$ of unit area in the $xy$-plane, we consider metrics $g=f^2(dx^2+dy^2)$ with the property that $\Omega$ contains a subdomain (say, a disk) $D$ on which Gaussian curvature $K\geq C>0$ and such that the $g$-area of $D$, i.e., $\int_D f^2 dxdy$, is at least $A>0$. We want to know whether there is a lower bound for $Var_\Omega(f)$ in terms of the constants $C$ and $A$.  Is there an optimal lower bound, and if so does a rotationally symmetric metric on a disk $D$ attain it? A similar question for $K$ negative and bounded away from $0$.

Comment: Variance with respect to what probability measure?

Comment: Say, $f$ is defined in a unit-area domain in the $x,y$ plane.  In Loewner's torus inequality, this is a fundamental domain for the torus.

Comment: @katz:  I'm not familiar with your notion of '$Var(f)$'.  Could you write down an explicit definition or formula?  Without it, I don't see how you expect to 'quantify' any conjectured relationship.  Also, when you write 'unit area domain', do you mean with respect to the standard measure in the $xy$-plane or with respect to the $g$-measure?

Comment: The variance is the minimum of $\int(f-m)^2$ over constant $m$.  The minimum is attained for $m=E(f)$, the expected value of $f$.  Moreover, $E(f^2)-(E(f))^2=Var(f)$.  From this combined with uniformisation one immediately deduces the strengthened form of Loewner's torus inequality.

Comment: The "unit area" is with respect to the standard area form $dxdy$.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the question, the answer is no: for any domain $\Omega$ and any $\delta>0$, denoting by $K_f$ the curvature function of the metric $g=f^2g_{eucl}$, we have

$$\inf_{K_f\geq\delta} \mathrm{Var}(f) = \inf_{K_f\leq-\delta} \mathrm{Var}(f) = 0$$

Indeed, given any $f$ such that $K_f\geq\delta$ and any $\lambda\in(0,1)$, the function $u=\lambda f$ has $\mathrm{Var}(u)=\lambda^2 \mathrm{Var}(f)$ and $K_u=K_f/\lambda^2\geq\delta/\lambda^2>\delta$.

This seems to have to do with normalization or the volume form which is used, but I do not know how one could formulate an alternative problem with a positive answer.

Comment: Are you proposing to take the limit as $\lambda\to 0$?  But then the disk where the curvature is bounded away from zero also has area tending to zero.  Obviously one needs a disk of a certain size where the curvature is bounded away from zero.  For rotationally invariant metrics one can actually get explicit estimates; see the second arxiv text.

Comment: Note also that scaling does not keep you in the class of probability measures, so your construction is unclear.

Comment: I guess I did not understand the question then. You are taking a domain of unit area with respect to $dx dy$, but you compute your integrals and variance according to the normalized volume of $g$?

Comment: The domain can be taken to be a parallelogram of unit area in the $x,y$ plane, say.  We have a function $f$ defining a new metric $f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$.  We are interested in the properties of this new metric.  This is a reasonable set-up in studying tori because by the uniformisation theorem, every torus is conformally equivalent to a flat torus (say of unit area), and the latter can be represented by a fundamental domain in the $(x,y)$ plane.  The variance of $f$ is calculated with respect to the flat metric of the $(x,y)$-plane because that's the term that arises in applying the formula...

Comment: ... the formula $E(f^2)-(E(f))^2=Var(f)$.  Here $E(f^2)$ is the total area of the new metric on the torus.  As far as the hypothesis of the disk of curvature bounded away from zero, its translation in terms of $(x,y)$ plane is that you have a domain where the metric $g=f^2(dx^2+dy^2$ is isometric to a distance ball of a fixed radius. A geometrically meaningful condition would have to be of this form (namely, expressed in terms of the intrinsic metric $g$).

Comment: @katz:  But Benoît is not changing the domain in the $xy$-plane, and certainly not scaling it, he is scaling down the metric $g$ and showing that the absolute value of the curvature blows up as the variance goes down, so you can't get a lower bound on the variance from a lower bound on the curvature.  You wrote something about a 'probability measure', which confused us, because you hadn't required that before.  Are you requiring that the $g$-area of the fixed domain $\Omega$ stay bounded away from $0$, say normalized to be $1$? Is that what you mean by 'probability measure'? 

Comment: Sorry to have confused everybody.  Let me try again.  I have a unit area region in the plane, and a function $f^2$ viewed as the conformal factor of a Riemannian metric.  I assume that there is a metric disk (for the new metric) where the curvature is bounded away from zero.  If you scale the metric, you will also scale the radius of the metric disk, so naturally you will get a weaker estimate, as Benoît pointed out.  Let me know if this is better.

Comment: @Robert Bryant: I am not sure where you mean your domain $\Omega$ to be.  If it is the original domain, then the answer is no, it is a unit area domain for the background flat metric, so that the Lebesgue measure in the plane defines a probability measure.  If you mean $\Omega$ to be the subdomain where the curvature is bounded away from zero, then yes, that's the metric $r$-disk I referred to earlier.  Its area needn't be normalized to 1, though, only bounded from below.

Comment: @katz:  Sorry, I'm still not clear on your hypotheses.  Would you agree with this:  On a fixed domain $\Omega$ of unit area in the $xy$-plane, we consider metrics $g = f^2(dx^2+dy^2)$ with the property that $\Omega$ contains a subdomain $D$ on which $|K|\ge C > 0$ and such that the $g$-area of $D$, i.e., $\int_D f^2\ dxdy$, is at least $A>0$ (and, maybe, $D$ contains a disk of $g$-radius $R>0$?).  We want to know whether there is a lower bound for $Var_\Omega(f)$ in terms of the constants $C$ and $A$ (and $R$?).  Is that your question (maybe without the $R$ condition)?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The formulation in terms of the subdomain $D$ is clearer because it consistently refers to domains in the $x,y$ plane.  The reason I wanted a metric ball with respect to $g$ is because such a condition is more geometrically meaningful (it does not depend on the conformal parametrisation by the plane domain $\Omega$), but yours is much clearer as experience shows.

Comment: P.S. Robert, thanks a lot! You saved the day.