# Stability of Pu's isosystolic inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, systolic-geometry

*The volume of a Riemannian metric on the projective plane is $2\pi$ and length of every non-contractible loop is greater than $\pi - \epsilon$ for some small, positive number $\epsilon$. Is this metric close to the canonical metric?*

The question is somewhat vague on purpose. I'm mostly interested in the best constant 
for a bilipschitz equivalence in terms of $\epsilon$, but I also wonder whether for some sufficiently small $\epsilon$ one can conclude that the curvature is close to 1.

Stability of inequalities is a well-trodden research topic in convex geometry and I was wondering what was known about this in systolic geometry.

Comment: An interesting "converse" would be to ask whether there is a lower bound for the "isosystolic defect" namely the difference between the area and $\tfrac{2}{\pi}\text{sys}^2$, in the assumption that the area is normalized to $2\pi$ and the curvature in a region of area $A$ is bounded away from $1$ by $\epsilon>0$.  For a related question see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127599/is-there-a-lower-bound-for-variance-in-terms-of-curvature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Lipschitz or even Gromov-Hausdorff stability - just consider a round metric with long hairy tails of small area.

One can hope for stability with respect to intrinsic flat distance in the sense of Sormani-Wenger or some similar metric. This distance is basically Federer's flat distance between isometric images is $L^\infty$ (just like the Gromov-Hausdorff distance is the Hausdorff distance in $L^\infty$). The stability in this sense probably amounts to uniqueness of the equality case in the class of integral current spaces arising as limits of projective planes.

Comment: Thanks Sergei. I was wondering about "sea urchins" myself and didn't know how to rule them out. Is that what the Sormani-Wenger metric can do? What about something terribly naive like a lipschitz stability for a nearly-full measure open subset? 





Comment: Uniformization (along the lines of Pu's proof) gives you a conformal factor $L^2$-close to 1. This implies Lipschitz closeness on nearly full measure.
